# How do I validate that a text input contains only latin letters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use jQuery to validate (on `keyup`) that a text input only contains latin letters (`only_english = 'abcdAbDKDk',`), without using a plugin?

Comment: Could you clarify the question and give more information on the subject? I really don't get your question.

Comment: Do you mean only Latin letters?

Comment: Do you want to verify that all of the words are actual words (spellcheck), or that there are only letters a-zA-Z?

Comment: I don't think this question would pass the validation. :)

Comment: Yes,i mean only Latin letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".latin-only").keypress(function(event) {
        if(!((event.which >= 65 && event.which  <= 90) ||
           (event.which >= 97 && event.which <= 122))) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }); 
});
```

If you want to allow spaces, add that to the statement above (|| event.which == 32).  You will need extra logic somewhere (perhaps in a change event, or keyup) to remove illegal chars from the string when users paste a value into the input.

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/4bPUE/2)

Comment: If value not mach `/[^a-zA-Z ]/`, not allow typed in the input, how is this?

Comment: The code above will set the variable "valid" to true if the control only contains the letters 'a' through 'z'.  If anything else is in the control, it will set the variable to false.  What you do with that is up to you - you could block form submissions, show the user a message (as this code does), change the value, ...?

Comment: I not want show a message, i want if letter not was latin letters, not type value in input. as this that just get number: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9zrw/2/