# Make validate for input that get only latin letters

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I validate that a text input contains only latin letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717363/how-do-i-validate-that-a-text-input-contains-only-latin-letters)

How can make a validate in `keyup` with jQuery that allow to input that get only latin letters and spaces, Like this that get just number in input: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9zrw/2/

How is it with jQuery?

```
<input type="text" name="type_ex" class="latin_letters">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the key up event you can reg exp your value: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9zrw/6/

```
$(this).val().replace(/[^a-z ]/i, "");
```

Replaces all that not match a-z and [    space    ] - case-insensitive. Means its match both lower and upper case letters.

Comment: And you can add 0-9 to your reg exp if you want to allow numbers to. And æøå or any other special characters if you want to allow any of these..

Comment: This is not a good practice.In the example, simply hold a number key and it will input numbers, therefore not working.

Comment: @DreamWave you can use **`/[^a-z ]/gi`**